# Extract certain dimensions from a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use the `tf.image_summary` function in tensorflow. I'm trying to visualize a convolutional layer's filter. The filter is defined as `tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[5, 5, 16, 32]))`.

But here, since I only want to see the final filters, I want to find a way to get a filter of size [5, 5, 32] by just taking the first index of the dimension that was 16. If I use [:, :, 0, :] then I assume I would get a [5, 5, 1, 32] filter instead of the [5, 5, 32] I want.

What should I do?

Comment: If your filter variable is called `filters` and you take the slice `filters[:, :, 0, :]`, then you should indeed get a tensor of shape `[5, 5, 32]`.

Comment: Also, in general, [`tensorflow.squeeze`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#squeeze) can be used to get ride of dimensions with size 1.

Answer (score 0):

So tf.image_summary takes in a batch as input however it expects 1,3,or 4 in terms of color channels.

so you'd have to pass in to tf.image_summary something like this:

```
for i in range(int(math.floor(filter.get_shape()[4]/3))):
    tf.image_summary(filter[:,:,:,i:i+3])
```